# Data sent to server but the request returns as failed on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I have an application where I send data to the server using `NSURLConnection`.. but there is a particular case where as soon as I hit the service and lock the iPhone. The data is received by the server but the `connectionDidFail` method is called inside the application.. is there any work around for this..?

Thanks for any inputs.

Comment: How much time it takes to receive the response to request (If you don't lock your iPhone)?

Comment: So, in this case, you are locking the phone immediately on sending the request?  You would like to have the successful request guaranteed to deliver to your app any time the server receives it?

Comment: The search for "background task while iphone is locked" -- You will find it easily.

Comment: Is this transaction required to be exactly-once delivered to the server or at-least-once?